# Applying K nearest neighbors algorithm causes issue with method train

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, knn

when i tried to implement k nearest Neighbors to my training datasets i have been created same as this photo

Python version 3.7.6

OpenCv version 4.2.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQNgq.png)

and same as this [code](https://pysource.com/2018/08/26/knn-handwritten-digits-recognition-opencv-3-4-with-python-3-tutorial-36/)

but instead of training only hand written numbers i have done it for chars and numbers based on font type i have done all the steps very well and all generated arrays is perfect

only KNN.train has problem i found some posts before said it has problem with old versions of Python but at same time i heard that cv2.ml.KNearest_create() still work  does ive dont something wrong

```
# KNN
knn = cv2.ml.KNearest_create()
knn.train(cells, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, cells_labels)
ret, result, neighbours, dist = knn.findNearest(test_cells, k=3)
```

it caused me strange error does it in compatible with python3.7.6

```
Traceback (most recent cakk kast):
    File "knn-apply.py", line 38, in <module>
       knn.train(cells.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, cells_labels)
RypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'responses'
```

Comment: Your provided code and the snippet that is producing the error do not correspond to each other.  BTW, `knn.train` takes in *three* input parameters.  You are only providing two.  Closing due to a simple typo.

Comment: i figured it out that the key value in the array should not be astring so i convert it intro the ASCII  code  then pass it to the knn.train method .